# Linking nested tables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to read the inner tables directly using the code below.

```
url='https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/AAKAR.html'
df_one=pd.read_html(url, header=0, match='Number of Booked Apartment')[1]
df_two=pd.read_html(url, header=0, match='Number of Booked Apartment')[2]
```

But how do I link the inner table with the main table? For e.g. the **df_one** frame mentioned above is linked to **serial Number 1** (outer). Is there any way to extract the outer table so that only serial number 1 and 2 is selected?

---

Update:

There is a section called "Building Details". If you visit the page, you will see the first serial number like this:

```
Sr.No.  Project Name    Name    Proposed Date of Completion Number of Basement's    Number of Plinth    Number of Podium's  Number of Slab of Super Structure   Number of Stilts    Number of Open Parking  Number of Closed Parking
1   SRUSHTI COMPLEX A and B     0   1   0   5   1   48  1
```

The second serial number is this:

```
Sr.No.  Project Name    Name    Proposed Date of Completion Number of Basement's    Number of Plinth    Number of Podium's  Number of Slab of Super Structure   Number of Stilts    Number of Open Parking  Number of Closed Parking
2   SRUSHTI COMPLEX C and D     0   1   0   5   1   51  1
```

The df_one dataframe is linked to Sr. No. 1 while df_two is linked to Sr. No. 2

I expect to add the columns of Sr. No. 1 and Sr. No. 2 to df_one and df_two respectively.

Comment: What do you mean by inner table, outer table and main table? It helps a lot if you can show the dataframes in question and the expected result - `df.head()` might be useful for that purpose.

Comment: You basically just need to parse the information out from the html. Relaying on `pandas.read_html` function is a wired way. Try using selector like `#DivBuilding > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)`, or even regular expression..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_html.html) says that you should be expecting to do some manual cleanup after calling `pd.read_html()`. I'm not sure how to extend this code to your possibly disparate htmls. With that being said, does this achieve what you want?

```
# Read df 
df_other=pd.read_html(url, header=0, match='Number of Plinth')

# To keep only the targeted columns; have a look at df_other -  it's cluttered.
targeted_columns = ['Sr.No.', 'Project Name', 'Name', 'Proposed Date of Completion',
       'Number of Basement\'s', 'Number of Plinth', 'Number of Podium\'s',
       'Number of Slab of Super Structure', 'Number of Stilts',
       'Number of Open Parking', 'Number of Closed Parking']

# 'Project Name'=='SRUSHTI COMPLEX' is an easy way to extract the two dataframes of interest. Also resetting index and dropping.
df_other = df_other[0].loc[df_other[0]['Project Name']=='SRUSHTI COMPLEX',targeted_columns].reset_index(drop=True)

# This is useful for the merge step later since the Sr.No. in df_one and df_two int
df_other['Sr.No.'] = df_other['Sr.No.'].astype(int)

# Extract the two rows as dataframes that correspond to each frame you mentioned
df_other_one = df_other.iloc[[0]]
df_other_two = df_other.iloc[[1]]
```

Once that is done, you can use `merge` to join the dataframes

```
df_one_ = df_one.merge(df_other_one, on='Sr.No.')
print(df_one_)

     Sr.No. Apartment Type  Carpet Area (in Sqmts)  Number of Apartment  \
0       1          Shops                   70.63                    6   

   Number of Booked Apartment     Project Name     Name  \
0                           0  SRUSHTI COMPLEX  A and B   

  Proposed Date of Completion Number of Basement's Number of Plinth  \
0                         NaN                    0                1   

  Number of Podium's Number of Slab of Super Structure Number of Stilts  \
0                  0                                 5                1   

  Number of Open Parking Number of Closed Parking  
0                     48                        1 


df_two_ = df_two.merge(df_other_two, on='Sr.No.')
print(df_two_)


     Sr.No. Apartment Type  Carpet Area (in Sqmts)  Number of Apartment  \
0       2           1BHK                 1409.68                   43   

   Number of Booked Apartment     Project Name     Name  \
0                           4  SRUSHTI COMPLEX  C and D   

  Proposed Date of Completion Number of Basement's Number of Plinth  \
0                         NaN                    0                1   

  Number of Podium's Number of Slab of Super Structure Number of Stilts  \
0                  0                                 5                1   

  Number of Open Parking Number of Closed Parking  
0                     51                        1
```

Comment: what if project name = 'SRUSHTI COMPLEX' is not known?

Comment: @shantanuo If the table structure is the same: we can use `iloc` to select the corresponding rows.

Comment: How can I use contains method instead of "==SRUSHTI COMPLEX" ?

Comment: df_other=df_other[0][df_other[0]['Project Name'].str.contains('SRUSHTI COMPLEX',  na=False)].reset_index(drop=True)